# Getting values from associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following main array called `$m`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [home] => Home
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contact_us] => Contact Us
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [about_us] => About Us
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [feedback_form] => Feedback Form
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [enquiry_form] => Products
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [gallery] => Gallery
        )

)
```

I have the values eg home, contact_us in a array stored $options , I need to get the values from the main array called $m using the $options array

eg. If the $options array has value home, i need to get the value Home from the main array ($m)

my code looks as follows

```
                    $c = 0;
                    foreach($options as $o){
                        echo $m[$c][$o];
                        ++$c;
                    }
```

I somehow just can't receive the values from the main array?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'd first transform `$m` to a simpler array with only one level:

```
$new_m = array();
foreach ($m as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $new_m[$key] = $value;
    } 
}
```

Then you can use:

```
foreach ($options as $o) {
    echo $new_m[$o];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach($options as $o){
    foreach($m as $check){
        if(isset($check[$o])) echo $check[$o];
    }
}
```

Although It would be better TO have the array filled with the only the pages and not a multidimensional array

Answer (score 1):

Assuming keys in the sub arrays are unique you can

1. merge all sub arrays into a single array using call_user_func_array on array_merge
2. swap keys and values of your option array
3. Use array_intersect_key to retrieve an array with all the values.

Example like so:

```
$options = array('about_us', 'enquiry_form');

$values = array_intersect_key(
           call_user_func_array('array_merge', $m), // Merge all subarrays 
           array_flip($options)                     // Make values in options keys
          );  

print_r($values);
```

which results in:

```
Array
(
    [about_us] => About Us
    [enquiry_form] => Products
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
foreach( $options as $option )
{
  foreach( $m as $m_key => $m_value )
  {
    if( $option == $m_key )
    {
      echo 'Name for ' . $options . ' is ' . $m_value;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the options array is in the same order of $m? Maybe you your

```
echo $m[$c][$o];
```

is resolving into a $m[0]['gallery'] which is obviously empty.

you can try different solutions, to me, a nice one (maybe not so efficient) should be like this:

```
for($c=0, $limit=count($c); $c < $limit; $c++)
  if (array_search(key($m[$c]), $options)) 
    echo current($m[$c]);
```

If you would like to use your approach have to flatten your array with something like this:

```
foreach ($m as $o)
  $flattenedArray[key($o)]=current($o);

foreach ($options as $o)
  echo $flattenedArray($o);
```

Doing this, though, eliminates duplicate voices of your original array if there are such duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a recursive array_walk function, for example

```
$a = array(
        array('ooo'=>'yeah'),
        array('bbb'=>'man')
    );


function get_array_values($item, $key){
    if(!is_numeric($key)){
        echo "$item\n";
    }
}

array_walk_recursive($a,'get_array_values');
```

Comment: You can effectively twist the function to create whatever you want from a tree-like array structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$trails1 = array();
          foreach ($trails as $item) {
              foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                  $trails1[].= $value;
              }

          }
          echo '<pre>';print_r($trails1);
        exit;
```