# is it possible to convert associative array to multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a form fields coming in the following format.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo '</pre>';exit;

[customer_id] = [0=> 4,1=>5];
[hobies]=>[0=> circket,1=>chess];
```

Here i want to convert into multidimensional associative array.

```
$output  = [
4=>[
'hobies'=>'circket'
],
5=>[
'hobies'=> 'chess'
]
];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$customer_id = array(4, 5);
$hobies = array('circket', 'chess');
$output = array();
foreach($customer_id as $index=>$cid){
    $output[$customer_id[$index]] = array("hobies"=>$hobies[$index]);
}
var_dump($output);
```

Output is

```
array(2) {
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["hobies"]=>
    string(7) "circket"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["hobies"]=>
    string(5) "chess"
  }
}
```

Comment: All the associative arrays are hard coded in your solution. That is not a general solution to this problem.

Consider for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536827/getting-values-from-associative-array

My goodness, php does make it hard, doesn't it, though